# Move 1px upwards for every pixel you move down

Tags: jquery, css

I have trouble finding a code that says if this site is scrolled down I want a div to move upwards at the same time, until I have scrolled past certain amount of pixels.

So if I scroll down like 100pixels, my div move upwards 100pixels, and when I pass by 120pixels the functions stops. When I scroll upwards again the function starts again but of course, the opposite effect.

Right now I have this code but I want it to be smooth and pixel by pixel, not just the effect when the poisiton is right.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
var a = 145;
var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
if(pos > a) {
    $("#mobil .holder").css({
                top: '0'
            });
}
else {
    $("#mobil .holder").css({
        top: '145px'
            });
}
});
```

Comment: Why not take a CSS route and make your DIV fixed until you hit a certain scroll point, then put it back into the flow?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use animate for the smoothness and check if pos is larger than 120 like this

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var pos = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('div').stop().animate({
        top: (pos >=120?120:pos)
    }, 1000);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/arnt0ynh/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Just use that :

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
    var a = 145;
    var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("#mobil .holder").css({
                top: -(Math.min(pos, 145))
            });
});
```

It negate the value of scroll top since you want it to move upward. The `Math.min()` is used to set a limit. It will never go above 145px.